# Send data from one xamarin.forms app to another xamarin.forms app

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to send data from one xamarin.forms app to another xamarin.forms app ? How do I implement it ?

Comment: One of the solutions is Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: I want to pass data from one installed app to another installed app..and as far as I know, GCM is used send notification data to targeted Android app.@Mr.Koçak

Comment: Ah ok i see.. I have forms app i implement gcm per plateform. If i remember well it works on ios..

Comment: What amount of data do you need to send?

Comment: I want to send an object @MichałŻołnieruk

Answer (score 0):

> send data from one xamarin.forms app to another xamarin.forms app

First you should open the app from another app. we can define the app is CallerApp the other is AnswerApp.

Take the xamarin android app as an example:

**In the CallerApp**

we can create a button in the CallerApp when the user click the button we transfer the data to another app.

```
 bt1.Click += Bt1_Click;
```

The click event:

```
    private void Bt1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent = this.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("your.answerapp.packagename");
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.PutString("hello", "hello");
        intent.PutExtra("hello",b);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

set your transfer data in the bundle.

**In the AnswerApp:**

We can received the intent in the OnCreate function :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   if (Intent.HasExtra("hello"))
   {
      var appData = Intent.Extras.GetBundle("hello").GetString("hello");
      Console.WriteLine("appData "+ appData);
   }
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
 }
```